# Error trying to update a Person Account

Tags: account

I get following error message:
INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Account: bad field names on insert/update call: Name: [Name]

even though I am not trying to update Name in my Person Account record.

Here is the code:

```
try {
    Account queriedContact = [SELECT Name 
                          FROM Account 
                          WHERE PersonEmail = 'test@test.com'
                          LIMIT 1];


    queriedContact.Motto__pc = 'My motto';
    update queriedContact;

} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
}
```

Any suggestion? Do I need to changes anything in my org settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `Name` variable in your query, Salesforce is concatenating `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`, and `Suffix` for you, which works fine when doing a query, however when you go to update that record, Salesforce doesn't want the concatenated version.

Try updating your query to not retrieve the name.  Use `Motto__pc` instead.  You'll need to query that field if you want to update it anyway.